# How can I update a given Eclipse bundle programmatically?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p2

I encounter some problems when I try to programmtically update specific Eclipse plug-ins.

I've uploaded the minimal set of projects that is needed to reproduce the problem on [github](https://github.com/reprogrammer/BundleUpdater). And, I've described the problem and the steps to reproduce it in details in [an issue on the github repository](https://github.com/reprogrammer/BundleUpdater/issues/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [UpdateOperation](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/equinox/p2/operations/UpdateOperation.html) is the simplest way to update the specified bundles.

You can specify the installed IUs to be updated via querying your profile.

```
IProfile profile = ...;
UpdateOpertation updateOperation = new UpdateOperation(session, profile.query(QueryUtil.ALL_UNITS, null).toSet());
```

But it's not a best practice to explicitly update all IUs. The best way is only updating the root IU(always is the product IU or top feature).

```
IProfile profile = ...;
UpdateOpertation updateOperation = new UpdateOperation(session, profile.query(QueryUtil.createIUQuery("theidofmyproductiu"), null).toSet());
```

Comment: The `Updater` class is already using `UpdateOperation`. Please see <https://github.com/reprogrammer/BundleUpdater/blob/master/edu.illinois.bundleupdater/src/edu/illinois/bundleupdater/Updater.java#L78>.

Comment: @reprogrammer, you don't understand the argument of UpdateOperation. The collection of IUs is a set of the installed IUs to be updated. See the updated answer.

Comment: What's more, if you install a bundle using a feature (becomes a root IU), the only way to find an update is the update both the feature.  p2 won't accept a bundle update while the feature is installed.